# Finite element ; integrating source terms and incompressibility equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have two simple questions about finite element :

The first one is :
Is it possible to integrate source terms to make them easier to calculate ?
Basically, I can write this : 
$\int \xi\cdot \nabla\sigma = -\int \nabla\xi \cdot\sigma$
The function $\xi$ is my test function, and $\sigma$ is just an independant function.

But will I be able to calculate it in my right hand side ?
The expression of sigma is complicated and it is a derivativ of a numerical function solved in another part of the code. So if I have to calculate the gradient of sigma I would have to use second order derivativs of this function which is not good I believe.

The second one is : do test function also have to respect the incompressibility equation ?
I have two variables that verifies an incompressibility equation.
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} =0$.
Then, during my calculation of the weak part, I use a test function written
$\xi = (\xi_u, \xi_v, \xi_p)$
And I have termes that appears in my weak form that are written $\frac{\partial \xi_u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \xi_v}{\partial y}$. So can I also write
$\frac{\partial \xi_u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial \xi_v}{\partial y} =0$ to simplify my weak formulation

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can do that if you deal with Dirichlet boundary conditions in the standard way and $\sigma$ is continuous. Indeed, on any generic domain $\Omega$
$$\int_\Omega \xi \nabla \sigma = \int_\Omega \nabla (\xi \sigma) - \nabla \xi \cdot \sigma = - \int_\Omega \nabla \xi \cdot \sigma + \int_{\partial\Omega} \xi \sigma \cdot n\,.$$
The last term vanishes because $\xi=0$ on $\partial\Omega$.

**Note:** continuity of $\sigma$ is important. If $\{K_i\}$ is a triangulation of $\Omega$, then
$$\int_\Omega \xi \nabla \sigma = \sum_i \int_{K_i} \xi \nabla \sigma =
 \sum_i - \int_{K_i} \nabla \xi \cdot \sigma + \int_{\partial K_i} \xi \sigma \cdot n.$$
Standard finite element functions like Lagrangian finite elements are continuous across $\partial K_i$ (note all finite elements are like this, though). However, if $\sigma\cdot n$ is not continuous across $\partial K_i$, you need to take jump terms into account.

2) Trial and test function do not always need to be divergence-free. For instance, in the Stokes' equation, the divergence-free constraint is imposed as a Lagrange multiplier (and neither the trial and test function employed are divergence-free). You can find more details about it in virtually any finite element textbook (or also [here](https://fenicsproject.org/docs/dolfin/1.4.0/python/demo/documented/stokes-taylor-hood/python/documentation.html)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !
1- Yes I use Direchlet Boundary Conditions. I forgot to say it. I was not really wondering about the mathematical calculus but more if it was also calculable numerically.
In my RHS, I usually always have terme that only depends linearly of my test function, and not its derivativ, so i wondered if It was doable.

2 - Yeah you're right, I was confused but it's more clear now. The divergence term I had was coming out of my stress tensor. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcomed ^_^ It is important the the RHS is linear and continuous. Usually, you use H1 spaces to formulate your problem, and in this case there's no problem if you have first derivatives of testfunctions in the RHS (but higher order derivatives are not allowed with H1).